# Putting an Excel Formula Within an IF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to set a cell to only display a date if there's a date in the reference cell. The date displayed needs to be exactly 1 year later so I'm using the following formula in cell C3:

```
=IF(B3="","","=DATE(YEAR(B3)+1,MONTH(B3),DAY(B3)")
```

The desired result is that if there is a date in B3, a date 1 year later will appear in C3. If there is no date in B3, C3 will remain blank.

Comment: Remove the quotes and second = sign: `=IF(B3="","",DATE(YEAR(B3)+1,MONTH(B3),DAY(B3)))`

Comment: Fantastic, this has solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're typing into a cell there are no speech marks -

```
=IF(B3="","",Date(year(b3)+1,month(b3),day(b3)))
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket for the IF. :)